# Non-inverting operational amplifier bandwidth

Tags: operational-amplifier, bandwidth

Image A: The circuit of which I am trying to calculate the bandwidth.

[image: Image A: The circuit of which I am trying to calculate the bandwidth]

I have been asked to calculate the bandwidth of this 741 op-amp circuit as part of my A Levels. I’ve done a lot of reading up on it and don’t know where to start. Could  someone guide me through the process or give me a starting point please?

I realised the image provided is not enough so I’ll add more results once I’m at a college computer.

Comment: Do you care about the input capacitance?

Comment: It's a bad idea to post half of the question. People will be reluctant to answer if you are planning to add more details, and by the time you get around to finishing the question it will be old and no one will bother. We've been waiting almost an hour now...to me that seems rude of you.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf - Not really, it was built as per the schematic with no capacitors.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson - I don’t have access to the college PC’s now, so I can’t load my document of results. I can do this at 9am UK Time.

Comment: Will, since you have done "a lot of reading" - which parts of the circuit do you think could be responsible for limitig the bandwidth?

Comment: Hint:  No external capacitors or inductors...ideal resistors won't affect bandwidth...what's left?

Comment: What do you mean by bandwidth? Do you mean full power bandwidth of the Op amp?

Comment: See also "slew rate" limiting ...

Answer (score 1):

1. Voltage Gain

First compute the voltage gain, which is equal:

$$A_V = 1+ \cfrac{R_2}{R_1}$$

In your case the R_2 = 150k and R_1 is 50k!

Hence

$$A_V = 1+\cfrac{150k}{50k} = 4$$

2. Bandwidth

For bandwidth compute 
$$\beta = \cfrac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} = \cfrac{50k}{50k + 150k} = 0.25 $$

and you get the bandwidth with:

$$f_B = \beta \cdot f_t \, ,$$

where f_t is the transit frequency of your opamp!

For a **741** as I remember it is typical 1 MHz; look at your data sheet!

$$f_B = 0.25 \cdot 1\mathrm{MHz} = 250\, \mathrm{kHz}\, .$$

Comment: @Will Now you have got an answer - and it s, in principle, correct. Do you know WHY it is correct? Do you know the background of the used formula ? Be prepared that your prof may ask such a question.

Comment: what do you mean in principle?

Comment: Because, the used transit frequency is a typical value only (the exact value is not known). More than that, the formula assumes a first order response for the open-loop gain only. This is a simplification - however, it is common practice.

Comment: That's right, but in electronic design you design the circuit in such a way, that in **worst case** it meets your requirements. Hence, you should use the worst case, or minimum transit frequency for designing your bandwidth.

Comment: What is the worst case?

Comment: abu_bua There is a small typing error in the last line of your answer.

Comment: @LvW: got it! The worst case: For instance high temperature, max. load, "bad sample" , ....

Comment: Yes - of course, You have mentioned the "environmental" conditions which influence the worst case. But - does it help at all for proper designing an electronic circuit? For a proper design we need an actual value for the open-loop gain (do you know if you have a "bad sample"?)

Comment: Worse, your answer is wrong by about a factor of 10. Small signal frequency response is not the only issue. Do a little research before you ask what the problem is.

Comment: The slew rate of the 53 years old 741 opamp is poor and limits the high frequency output level.